# public Azure Function that can overwrite and save files in wwwroot of other azure applications? in particular aspx and run.csx files

Tags: azure, permissions, ide, azure-functions, edit

possible to have a public Azure Function that can overwrite and save code files in wwwroot of other azure applications? in particular aspx and run.csx files?

I understand the security risks, but the idea to have the Azure Function do this with a hard coded specific service account with rights and for two very specific aspx and run.csx files.

Neither of these requires a compile step in the Azure portal UI and wonder about that as well.

Just a question, not looking for best practices or reasons why we should not do this.

Comment: you can upload files, but function's wwwroot should be no business with other app. Does this situation you ask make any sense?

Comment: I think there is no such thing as ‘‘ overlay ’’. Did I misunderstand your problem? The wwwroot of the function app is independent of the wwwroot of other web apps.

Comment: looking to build a very limited and simple editor for just two code files.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to compile, just save the code and files,that is no problem.

But it can only be saved, it will not be a real web app, just some files.

You can use zip deploy or FTP to deploy the azure function app to azure and include the files you want to save.

If you Use zip deploy, just zip the files and code with the function app. And then use this command to deploy them to azure:

**Azure CLI:**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

**PowerShell:**

```
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <app-name> -ArchivePath <zip-file-path>
```

This is offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

**Or you can use FTP to upload files.**

[image]

Go to this place to get the host name:

[image]

Go to this place to get the username and password:

[image]

And then use them to connect to your function physical path:

[image]

At last you can upload anything to the wwwroot of your function app on azure.

This is the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rewrite the file under wwwroot folder, yes this is possible.

I have two function in the portal, in the `HttpTrigger1` function I rewrite the `HttpTrigger2` content. Below is `HttpTrigger2` original content.

[image]

Below is `HttpTrigger1` code, write a string to `HttpTrigger2` run.csx.

[image]

Here is the result, after running `HttpTrigger1`, the `HttpTrigger2` content is changed.

[image]