# Django app 'deployment successful' to Azure, but URL is just showing the default page instead of my code's app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

I'm trying to deploy my app to Azure app service through VScode and I followed tutorial steps and can see this within my output on Azure App Service output terminal:

```
11:24:00 PM trendallarchive: Activating virtual environment...
11:24:00 PM trendallarchive: Could not find setup.py or requirements.txt; Not running pip install
```

I can see there was an issue with my requirements.txt file, but I'm not sure why it couldn't find it. Would this be the cause of my code not deploying? even though it says deployment successful? If the requirements.txt file exists then how come I am receiving this output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: no it didn't solve my problem. i moved my requirements.txt to the root of the app and it solved that error but the app isnt deployed still. I have discovered that my apps files aren't in wwwroot so i think thats why but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: To move apps files to `wwwroot`, you can refer to  [App doesn't appear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#app-doesnt-appear). You can use zip deploy or FTP to deploy the azure app to azure and include the files you want to save. References: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip20.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207887/public-azure-function-that-can-overwrite-and-save-files-in-wwwroot-of-other-azur, https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-azure-functions-wwwroot-folder/